# Arduino Program Successfully Uploaded, but Serial Monitor Shows No Output

Tags: arduino-uno

I've written an Arduino program that utilizes an ultrasonic sensor to measure distance and display it via the Serial Monitor. The program was successfully uploaded, but there's no output showing up on the Serial Monitor.

I've checked the wiring to ensure it's correct and verified the ultrasonic sensor and Arduino board. Everything seems to be in order.

Here's my Arduino sketch:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QCkg.png)

Verbose Output (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEgmb.png) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRv5K.png)

Serial Monitor (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM7DO.png)

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, and not a screenshot.